# Is there a way to propagate multiple injection?

Tags: c#, ninject

I'm trying to get Ninject to resolve a dependency tree that requires it to create multiple objects depending on how many bindings of a dependency there are.

For example, suppose I have this type system:

```
public class A : IA
{
    public A(IB[] bs) { /* ... */ }
}

public class B : IB
{
    public B(IC c) { /* ... */ }
}

public class C1 : IC
{
    public C1() { /* ... */ }
}

public class C2 : IC
{
    public C2() { /* ... */ }
}

public interface IA { }
public interface IB { }
public interface IC { }
```

Can I configure Ninject to do something like this?

```
var a = new A(new IB[]
{
    new B(new C1()),
    new B(new C2())
});
```

I do not want to create an IB implementation that takes multiple IC types, because IB is tied logically to working with a single IC type. It is much easier to handle multiple instances of IB a level higher.

I hoped just doing this would work:

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel();
kernel.Bind<IC>().To<C1>();
kernel.Bind<IC>().To<C2>();
kernel.Bind<IB>().To<B>();
kernel.Bind<IA>().To<A>();

var a = kernel.Get<IA>();
```

But it throws an exception:

```
Error activating IC
More than one matching bindings are available.
Matching bindings:
  1) binding from IC to C1
  2) binding from IC to C2
Activation path:
  3) Injection of dependency IC into parameter c of constructor of type B
  2) Injection of dependency IB into parameter bs of constructor of type A
  1) Request for IA
```

Comment: Ninject could do it, as long as you do not have circular dependencies.

Comment: IMO, you have crossed the line where [Pure DI](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/) becomes a better alternative than using a DI Container. You are basically creating a "complex object graph". See my article here for more details: http://criticalsoftwareblog.com/index.php/2015/08/23/why-di-containers-fail-with-complex-object-graphs/

Comment: A factory that spits out first a `C1`, then a `C2` would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

A possibility is to create multiple bindings for all combinations of `IB` + `IC`:

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel();
kernel.Bind<IB>().To<B>()
    .WithParameter(
        new TypeMatchingConstructorArgument(
            typeof(IC), 
            (ctx, target) => ctx.Kernel.Get<C1>()));
kernel.Bind<IB>().To<B>()
    .WithParameter(
        new TypeMatchingConstructorArgument(
            typeof(IC),
            (ctx, target) => ctx.Kernel.Get<C2>()));
kernel.Bind<IA>().To<A>();

var a = kernel.Get<IA>();
```